# Serial monitor error message

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, error

I connected my ArduCam mini to es8266 board and opened serial monitor. Then this message appeared. It started to appear continuously. I used the code in examples "functions of ov2640". What does it mean?  Why that message appears?  Plz help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it is a watchdog reset. the code doesn't go out of the loop() function

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: I used 
"extern "C" {
    #include "user_interface.h"
}" in the code before the setup functions

Comment: add the sketch to the question

Comment: You can "fix" it by removing long loops (while, etc) from your code.

Comment: I have added the code as an answer below..

Comment: Add the code to your question by editing it. Also format it correctly by selecting it and clicking the `{}`  button

Comment: the sketch is not for esp8266

Comment: Is there any example sketch in arduino IDE which i can use to capture image from arducam with esp8266?

Comment: @juraj this is the task what i want to do.                        Capture image through arducam mini ov2640 and save it to SD card attached to nodemcu. How can i find the sketch to do this task?

Comment: https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/master/ArduCAM/examples/ESP8266/ArduCAM_ESP8266_V1_OV2640_Capture2SD/ArduCAM_ESP8266_V1_OV2640_Capture2SD.ino

Comment: I tried using the code you gave in github. Again it shows an error saying "ArduCam start! SPI1 interface error!"

Comment: did you wire D0 as CS? the sketch uses io 16 (D0) as SPI CS

Comment: I connected cs pin in arducam to D0 in nodemcu